# Pandas: Calling df.loc[] from an index consisting of pd.datetime

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Say I have a df as follows:

```
a=pd.DataFrame([[1,3]]*3,columns=['a','b'],index=['5/4/2017','5/6/2017','5/8/2017'])    
a.index=pd.to_datetime(a.index,format='%m/%d/%Y')
```

The type of of the df.index is now

```
<class 'pandas.core.indexes.datetimes.DatetimeIndex'>
```

When we try to call a row of data based on the index of type pd.datetime, it is possible to call the value based on a string format of date instead of inputting a datetime object. In the above case, if I want to call a row of data on 5/4/2017, I can simply input the string format of the date to .loc as follows:

```
print(a.loc['5/4/2017'])
```

And we do not need to input the datetime object

```
print(a.loc[pd.datetime(2017,5,4)]
```

My question is, when calling the data from .loc based on string format of date, how does pandas know if my date string format follows m-d-y or d-m-y or other combinations? In this above case, I used a.loc['5/4/2017'] and it succeeds in returning the value. Why wouldn't it think it might mean April 5 which is not within this index?

Answer (score 1):

Here's my best shot:

Pandas has an internal function called pandas._guess_datetime_format. This is what gets called when passing the 'infer_datetime_format' argument to pandas.to_datetime. It takes a string and runs through a list of "guess" formats and returns its best guess on how to convert that string to a datetime object.

Referencing a datetime index with a string may use a similar approach.

I did some testing to see what would happen in the case you described - where a dataframe contains both the date 2017-04-05 and 2017-05-04.

In this case, the following:

```
df.loc['5/4/2017']
```

Returned the Data for May 4th, 2017

```
df.loc['4/5/2017']
```

Returned the data for April 5th, 2017.

Attempting to reference 4/5/2017 in your original matrix gave an "is not in the [index]" error.

Based on this, my conclusion is that pandas._guess_datetime_format defaults to a "%m/%d/%Y" format in cases where it cannot be distinguished from "%d/%m/%Y". This is the standard date format in the US.

Comment: thank you for your thoughtful answer. I am suspecting if the string format used depends on the language / date setting of windows / os?

Comment: From [IO Tools Documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20/io.html) :

While US date formats tend to be MM/DD/YYYY, many international formats use DD/MM/YYYY instead. For convenience, a dayfirst keyword is provided.

The `dayfirst` keyword could be used to correctly read international dates when parsing a .csv file, but I'm not sure if you have the option of setting `dayfirst` from `.loc`. Your best bet for finding an answer is probably to poke around in the source code, but it may be the case that .loc just always operates with `dayfirst=False`.